# Can't set header background of a table the way I want

Tags: css

I’m trying to adapt some css code I found, however my table seems ugly (according to me). I'll explain this on a picture.

css:

```
td, th {
    border-left: 1px solid #494437;
    border-top: 1px solid #494437;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;    
}

th {
    background-color: #b8ae9c;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    border-top: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

td:first-child, th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```

I explained what I want by an image:

[image]

**EDIT:** For example I expect white area on right side, when I add *padding-right: 0.2em;* into "th". But it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please try to explain clearly what you want to achieve and where you are stuck. Add your HTML and remove the irrelevant parts (like animation) from your CSS. There is a lot of 'noise' in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting?

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
}

.header {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
  background-color: #b8ae9c;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, exactly what I want! I'll try to adapt this to table tags. thanks a lot.